# jar file execution through informatica java trasformation

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

I have a jar file, when I run it it will get the source from one data base and it will write the target in to another database
is there any possibility to automate the running of this jar file through informtica

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple solutions for this. You could simply use a command task in a workflow to call your jar and then schedule this workflow periodically. Or you could use a java transformation to call java code.

However, getting data from a source and writing it to target database is exactly what PowerCenter was built for so hiding all logic inside a jar file and using PowerCenter only to invoke it might not be the cleanest solution. Even if you're simply trying to reuse existing code.